Видимость внешних таблиц в CROSS APPLY
Казалось бы, значение из строки внешнего датасета должен быть видимым внутри. Рабочий пример:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_2 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 2 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 5 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 col_id, 7 val FROM dual
),
table_3 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 2 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 5 val FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 6 col_id, 7 val FROM dual
)
SELECT *
  FROM table_1 t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT *
                 FROM table_2 t2
                WHERE t2.col_id in (SELECT t2.col_id
                                      FROM table_3 t3
                                     WHERE t2.col_id = t1.col_id));

Но почему-то в случае рекурсивного запроса я столкнулся с проблемой видимости. Не рабочий пример:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_parents AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 col_id, 4 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.col_id
     , uptimate_parent.parent_id
  FROM table_1 t1
  CROSS APPLY (SELECT parent_id
                 FROM (select col_id, parent_id FROM table_parents WHERE parent_type = 'manager') pars
                WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
                START WITH pars.col_id = t1.col_id
              CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR pars.parent_id = pars.col_id) uptimate_parent;

Этот код вызовет ошибку:

[42000][904] ORA-00904: "T1"."COL_ID": invalid identifier

ругаясь на обращение внутри CROSS APPLY. В чем я не правильно понимаю логику CROSS APPLY здесь, почему во втором случае подзапрос не видит значение из строки в месте вызова подзапроса?
Самое интересное, что просто переместив CROSS APPLY подзапрос в SELECT-лист, запрос становится вполне рабочим (да, в тестовых данных не случайно высший родитель только один). То есть этот запрос вполне рабочий:
WITH table_1 AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 col_id FROM dual
),
table_parents AS (
  SELECT 1 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 col_id, 3 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 col_id, 4 parent_id, 'manager' parent_type FROM dual
)
SELECT t1.col_id
     , (SELECT parent_id
          FROM (select col_id, parent_id FROM table_parents WHERE parent_type = 'manager') pars
         WHERE connect_by_isleaf = 1
         START WITH pars.col_id = t1.col_id
       CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR pars.parent_id = pars.col_id) uptimate_parent
  FROM table_1 t1;


Я реализовал этот запрос через джойн, но мне интересно понять, что я понимаю не правильно про CROSS APPLY

То, что в скобках, выполняется же раньше чем то, что снаружи, по идее

@CrazyElf Я даже не знаю как на это отреагировать, если честно. Только предложить погуглить про кореллирующие подзапросы могу.

У тебя получается два уровня вложенности. А сам параметр при этом должен в этом случае передаться во внутренний подзапрос, т.е. через уровень, что невозможно. Что это - интерпретация Оракла или результат работы его оптимизатора, фиг знает. Предлагаю вместо подзапроса использовать всю таблицу, а условие parent_type = 'some_val' переместить во WHERE рекурсивного подзапроса или в START WITH (в зависимости от требуемой логики). По идее, должно работать.

этот запрос вполне рабочий А тут уже нет вложенности. Оттого и запрос работает нормально.

@Akina, добавил тестовые данные в вопрос. К сожалению, ваша идея не сработала. Текст коммента не позволяет добавить измененный по вашей идее скрипт с переносом parent_type во WHERE секцию для упразднения подзапроса pars (длинновато выходит). Плюс в виде подзапроса в SELECT-листе вполне работает и в таком виде рекурсивный подзапрос (тоже добавил в вопрос).

@Akina, также добавил изменение в первый рабочий запрос чтобы показать, что данные из внешней строки можно пробросить во вложенный подзапрос внутри кореллирующего подзапроса.

@Akina, возможно причина в версии оракла. Это "не рабочий" запрос работает в версии 18C https://dbfiddle.uk/oZ4EBZqr Но у меня 12C.

К сожалению, у меня нет под рукой версии 12С, только то, что предлагают online fiddle. См. вариант https://dbfiddle.uk/43W5Zb4K , может, он подхватится твоей версией.  Да и непонятно, что там длинноватого получается.

@Akina длинноватый комментарий получается чтобы вставить его - я час назад не знал про dbfiddle чтобы вам продемонстрировать текст скрипта, а в вопрос добавлять не хотелось. Но именно такой скрипт я попробовал выше, да он не робит. В англоязычной SO предположили, что в 12c еще сырой был CROSS APPLY, может там могут находиться такие вот баги. Песочницы на 12c с разбега тоже не нагуглилось что-то.

Ну тогда просто спишем на версию, и фиг бы с ею... А песочницы оракловые вообще редкость. Я только 5 штук знаю, из которых доступны только 3, и на dbfiddle самый большой набор версий.
